# ' versus #' what are the differences and when should I choose one over the other?

Tags: functions, quote

Both seem to work equally well when mapping a function over a list, for example.

```
(mapcar #'1+ (list 1 2 3))
;; => (2 3 4)
(mapcar '1+ (list 1 2 3))
;; => (2 3 4)
```

Comment: @Basil. Yes, righto.

Answer (score 2):

`#'` (= `function`) is more verbose than `'` (= `quote`), and it provides three practical benefits.

### 1. Byte compiler will check if the function is defined

Byte compile a file which contains the following code

```el
(mapc #'2+ nil)
(mapc  '3+ nil)
```

The byte compiler will warns us that `2+` is not defined:

> foo.el:3:1:Warning: the function `2+' is not known to be defined.

Although `3+` is also not defined, we won't get a warning because we're using `'`.

## 2. The code will be more precise to us

For example, when I see this two function calls, I will get more precise 
 information

```el
(foo #'bar) ;; => foo accepts a function and bar is a function
(foo  'bar) ;; => foo accepts a symbol
```

## 3. The code completion will be more precise

`#'` completes only symbols with a function definition while `'` completes any symbols (functions/variables/faces etc).

Answer (score 1):

`quote` (`'`) returns its argument sexp - any Lisp object (thing).

`function` (`#'`) returns its argument sexp as a function object. This also means that in code you byte-compile it tells the byte compiler that that thing is a function.

`'foobar` just evaluates to the symbol `foobar`. `#'foobar` evaluates to a function.

`'(lambda) () (something))` evaluates to the **list** whose car is the symbol `lambda`, whose cadr is `nil`, and whose caddr is the list `(something)`.  There is no way for the byte-compiler or any code that uses this return value to know that that list is to be interpreted/used as a function (except code that in fact uses it that way).  `#'(lambda () (something))` evaluates to a function that accepts no arguments and invokes function `something` (passing it no args). (`(lambda () (something)` evaluates to the same function - unquoted `lambda` forms are self-evaluating.)

In Lisp, data and code (programs) have the same syntax.  `(lambda () (something)` is both a list (when not evaluated) and a function (when evaluated).  When you quote such a list, `'(lambda () (something))`, you get just that list, not a function.

If you then use that list as a function, it works, because when evaluated it is interpreted as a lambda form, which returns an anonymous function (which can have the same form as the lambda form itself).

When Emacs - in particular the byte compiler - can *know* that some bit of code is a function it can act accordingly, error-check, optimize, etc. If all Emacs knows is that there is a list whose car is the symbol `lambda` etc., there's no way it can or should make any assumption about it representing a function. The code in which it occurs could use it in some other way.

See the Elisp manual, nodes [Anonymous Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions.html) and [Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html).